# I need to call a controller by passing the param from the view on clicking the ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to search a student and display the student record based on the value entered on textbox. I am not sure how to pass the value without using Jquery. Is there a way.

**Controller:**

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult GetStudentsByName(string name)
        {
            SchoolDbEntities db = new SchoolDbEntities();
            var student = db.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName.Contains(name));
            return View(student);

        }
```

**View**

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.SearchEntity.StudentName,"Search Student")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchEntity.StudentName, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
            </div>

        </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">

                <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetStudentsByName", "Student")'" class="btn btn-primary">Search <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

                <button id="Reset"
                        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i> &nbsp;Reset
                </button>
            </div>
```

I need to pass the param , In the @Url.Action("GetStudentsByName", "Student", new {@name= 'value from the textbox')

Also it is a Get Method and not httpPost.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the input form element inside a form control and submit the form via GET method.

Make sure the input element name matches with your action method parameter name

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetStudentsByName","Student",FormMethod.Get))
{       
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search </button>
}
```

Comment: so if i click on the button,  and put a breakpoint on the controller method, will it get paused at the break point? I am trying the same but not happening

Comment: yes. When you click the search button, it will submit the form to `GetStudentsByName` action method via a GET method. so you will see the name entered in the textbox in the querystring. if you put a breakpoint in your `GetStudentsByName` action method and inspect the value of `name` param, you should be able to see the same value in the querystring.

Comment: Make sure your button is submit type as i have in the answer.

Comment: Hi @shyju I tried the same, but it is not invoking the GetStudentByName action method. By default it goes to the Index method. I verified and copied the same thing but still not working.

Comment: Do you have nested form. That could be one reason this form is not working because it is inside another form. Nested forms are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont wanna make the button a submit button then by giving your text box a specific class you can do it .

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.SearchEntity.StudentName,"Search Student")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchEntity.StudentName, new { @class = "form-control,txt-input" }) 
        </div>

    </div>

<div class="panel-footer">

            <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetStudentsByName", "Student",new { data= "STUDENT_NAME" })'.replace("STUDENT_NAME", $('.txt-input').val())" class="btn btn-primary">Search <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

            <button id="Reset"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i> &nbsp;Reset
            </button>
        </div>
```

I tried something like this long back , i think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetStudentsByName", "Home"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StudentName, "Search Student")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StudentName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search"  class="btn btn-primary" />
}
</div>
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult GetStudentsByName()
    {
            string name =  Request.Form["StudentName"]
            SchoolDbEntities db = new SchoolDbEntities();
            var student = db.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName.Contains(name));
            return View(student);
    }
```

using `Request.Form["StudentName"]` you can access the value from view to controller. Also, one more suggestion, use `using` statement it helps to manage unhandled memory. For example

```
public ActionResult GetStudentsByName()
{
       string name =  Request.Form["StudentName"]
       using(SchoolDbEntities db = new SchoolDbEntities())
       {
        var student = db.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName.Contains(name));
        return View(student);
       }
}
```